# Github Page local repository recovery

Tags: github, github-pages, hexo

I have a Hexo blog set up on the GitHub and it works fine for me.
This afternoon, I deleted the local repository by accident and I am trying to recover it from the GitHub (Clone the copy from GitHub).

[image]

I figure out, the files on GitHub was actually the content in the public folder of local repository.
How can I recover my local repository as the one I deleted this afternoon?
My assumption is init a Hexo blog in one empty folder and drag files on Github into the public folder, I have tried and it doesn't work.
  As I don't want to set it up from the beginning.

Comment: Did you only deploy to GitHub pages or did you save your sources on GitHub as well (probably on a different branch)?

Comment: Yeah, I just deploy my GitHub Pages and I did not save the sources on Github. It sucks, is there a way to recover it?

Comment: There are (experimental) html2markdown converters, but depending on the amount of blog posts, sites, etc. I'd probably set it up again using copy & paste. Maybe if you post the GitHub repo URL, someone might have a good idea to help

Comment: Might be a good idea

Answer (score 1):

I have the same trouble before, and It's impossible to recover your source code from the public folder. I think you should think of how to recover the deleted from your computer hardware.

Comment: You are right and I have done that. Thanks for sharing anyway